# error:camera calibration with openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, camera, calibration

I'm trying to calibrate my camera but I have some errors. When I try to compile the program in opencv/samples/calib3d.cpp, CodeBlocks tells me that I have errors in calib3d.hpp. I did some research and I find the probleem is in

```
#define CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS   
#define CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO
```

so if I gave a value to this lign, for exemple

```
#define CV_CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS   1
#define CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO 2
```

The program now works, so how can I find the exact value required? Is there any other way to make the program work?

Comment: Did you include correctly the library in your project? I mean from project option

Comment: yes,I didn't change anything

Comment: which os are you using? I found difference in windows and Linux